# Converting a layer file (*.lyr) to a QGIS compatible file without using ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, layer-file

I have some `.lyr` files and I need to be able to open them in QGIS.
I don't have access to ArcGIS so I need to convert those files to another format compatible with QGIS (`.qlr`, `.xml`, `.sld`, `.style`,...) either using QGIS or another tool (preferably an open source one) .

Comment: there is a commerical tool for this: https://north-road.com/slyr/ but the price is too hight for an occassional user, but maybe you can ask the developer, if he can offer conversion of your files for a special fee

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile there is a free Community-Version of the commercial [SLYR- Plugin for QGIS](https://github.com/north-road/slyr) available, which you can download directly in QGIS. You should definitly give it a try

**update:** the new qlyrx lets you apply esri ArcGISPro .lyrx symbology files to your qgis-vectorlayers. As I dont use any esri-files, I did not test this myself, but you should give the new plugin a try

Comment: This free Community-Version version seem to "only" convert from ESRI .style databases to corresponding QGIS symbology, so it won't work for .lyr

Comment: please see my updated answer

Comment: The question is about the `.lyr` format, not `.lyrx`. `qlyrx` cannot use the former. However, SLYR is a functional option at present.

Comment: It requires a licensed version to convert map server layers.